# How do I process Multiple get parameters in python flask?

Tags: python, flask, get

I want to take 'age' as an input from user, and also the gender. Now I want to check that whether two things:

```
age>18 and gender=Male
```

I used the following routing in my flask code.

```
@app.route('/checkAge', methods=['GET'])
def foo():
    age= request.args.get('age')
    gender =  request.args.get('gender')
    if(gender=='Male'&&age>18):
        print age-5
```

the url that I used to access the route:

```
/createcm?gender=Male&age=20
```

Still I am getting some Internal server error. 
Please help me out that how to process values taken from the get parameters in flask.

Comment: Are you doing a `GET` or a `POST` to the server?

Answer (score 1):

```
if(gender=='Male'&&age>18):
```

is not python

try

```
if(gender=='Male' and age>18):
```

additionally you should set your `app.debug=True` which would have told you this

you should also probably be casting age to an int before trying to compare it

```
if(gender=='Male' and int(age)>18):
   return "You are an adult male!"
```

to answer your other totally unrelated question that you posted in the comments

```
@app.route('/createcm', methods=['GET'])
def foo():
    return str(request.args.get("age",type=int) + request.args.get("weight",type=int))
```

Comment: You can also cast to an integer with `request.args.get('age', type=int)`.

Comment: Basically, I want to add height and weight and print it.
So there is my code and is not working.
In url, its : /createcm?age=19&weight=20

`@app.route('/createcm', methods=['GET'])
def foo():
    print request.args.get('age', type=int)
    request.args.get('weight', type=int)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    port = int(os.environ.get('PORT',5000))
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port= port, debug = True)`
How do I get 39 as the outpt in my screen?

Comment: How do I get the output as 39 now on my page? 
Basically I want to play with the get requests in flask. So that I can implement my algorithms by taking get requests.

Comment: I did that also, but it is again giving application error. Here is what I requested in url: 
`https://alfa-server2.herokuapp.com/createcm?age=19&weight=20`
and the repostiory is  [here](https://github.com/shubhodeep9/alfa-health-python/blob/master/server.py)

Comment: you have some other server error ... what does your logs say?

Comment: on line 7 try adding `app.debug = True`  im pretty sure its serving the page without triggering the if name == main bit

Comment: The same thing @JoranBeasley, Application error.. I am not sure i edited the repository correctly or not! Can you make the pull request?

Comment: I dont think you are even triggering your app at all ... I think it is falling down earlier ... you should really find out where the server logs are in heroku and read them (in apache2 they are at `/var/log/appache2/errors.log`, usually)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84016/discussion-between-ashwini-purohit-and-joran-beasley).